# Integrated Security=true is trying to log me with my windows credentials even though I want to use SQL authentication

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working on `ASP.NET Web Forms` application, using standard `ADO.NET` for quering the database. Since today I've been developing on my local machine, using local resources (including local isntance of `SQL Server 2008`) and I use a very simple connections string plus `Windows auth` to connect to my database:

```
<add name="MyConn" connectionString="Data Source=MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
Catalog=MyDataBaseName;Integrated Security=true;"/>
```

But today I wanted to remove to a remote `SQL SERVER` so I changed my connection string accordingly:

```
<add name="MyConn" connectionString="Data Source=TheRemoteServer;
Initial Catalog=MyDataBaseName;User Id=MyId;Password=MyPassword;
Integrated Security=true;"/>
```

and when I try to connect to the database, when I reach :

```
 try
 {
   connection.Open();
```

I get an error that connection can not be established for user and here come my Windows user instead the ID I've provided in the connection string. However if I set `Integrated Security=false;` (to False) everything starts working. I don't know why. It seems strange and since it obviously has something to do with security I'm bothered leaving it like that. So what are my options here?

Comment: `Integrated Security=true;` in the connection string tells ADO.Net to connect to SQL Server via Windows Authentication.  Since you are providing `User Id` and `Password` for SQL Authentication, you can omit `Integrated Security` from the connection string.

Comment: "since it obviously has something to do with security" - yes, but if you look into it just a bit further, the bit it has to do with security is to use Windows authentication rather than SQL Server authentication. It doesn't have any other security effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Integrated Security:**

> When false, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.
>
> Recognized values are true, false, yes, no, and sspi (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to true.
>
> If User ID and Password are specified and Integrated Security is set to true, the User ID and Password will be ignored and Integrated Security will be used.
>
> SqlCredential is a more secure way to specify credentials for a connection that uses SQL Server Authentication (Integrated Security=false).

[SQL Credential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcredential%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Wow, Thanks for the nformation. Very useful indeed!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following:

```
<add name="MyConn" connectionString="Data Source=TheRemoteServer;
Initial Catalog=MyDataBaseName;User Id=MyId;Password=MyPassword;"/>
```

### or

```
<add name="MyConn"  ConnectionString="Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;
Database=myDataBase;User Id=MyId;Password=myPassword;"/>
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I get it working. But is `DMason` right when say that `Integrated Security` is used only to point if I want to use Windows or SQL authentication? My worries come from eventual sequrity issues from setting it to false!?